# unordered_map::find not working for strings

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, unordered-map

The following piece of code is means to make a dictionary (using an `unordered_map`), make keys for the dictionary (out of words from `wordlist`), and add anagrams (of each key) from `wordlist` in the vector corresponding to the key. The function then returns the vector corresponding to parameter `word` (which is the vector containing all anagrams of `word`).

```
vector<string> anagram(string word, vector<string> wordlist)
{
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> map;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++)
    {
        string temp = wordlist[i];
        sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
        
        if (map.find(temp) != map.end())
        {
            map.find(temp) -> second.push_back(wordlist[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            vector<string> vect;
            map.insert(make_pair(temp, vect));
            //seg-faulting at the following line
            map.find(temp) -> second.push_back(wordlist[i]);
        }
        
        if (map.find(word) != map.end())
            cout << map.find(word) -> first << endl;
    }
    
    return map.find(word) -> second;
}
```

The input list `wordlist` is basically a `vector` of length ~170,000 containing two-letter all the way to twenty-eight-letter English words. I believe the problem is the `unordered_map::find` function; however, I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: 1) Don't call your variable `map`.  There is already a `std::map` class.  2) Why not simply: `map[temp].push_back(wordList[i]);`?  C++ is not Java, where you have to write code to check for an empty map.  That single line of code replaces all of the convoluted logic you're doing now.

Comment: In addition, you should be passing the vector by const reference, not by value.  By passing by value, you are creating a temporary copy of the vector (which you say has thousands of strings).  IMO, this looks like you're writing C++, but using Java as a model.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Actually, the function template (as well as some code structure) was provided by an instructor, and since he is using an auto-grader, only a very specific solution will pass... nevertheless, implementing your suggestions solved plenty of the problems. The `map` variable name will have to stay though; the auto-grader requires it (talk about bad programming practice)

Comment: Your algorithm will crash if `word` itself is not sorted (meaning, its characters are not arranged in alphabetical order). Since all keys in `map` are, by construction, sorted, `map.find(word)` won't find anything, and `map.find(word) -> second` would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't see why you need `map` at all. Why waste memory storing anagrams for the whole dictionary, when you are only interested in anagrams for `word`? Just skip all elements in `wordList` where `temp != word_sorted` (where `word_sorted` is the result of sorting `word`); push the rest onto a vector that will be the result. Also, before comparing (or even sorting) strings, you can compare their sizes, and skip all elements where `wordList[i].size() != word.size()`. If `wordList` is sorted by increasing string size, as you appear to suggest. you can exit early once you get to longer strings.

Comment: I agree; my instructor is trying to give us experience with dictionaries, though!